# Make custom type "tie-able" (compatible with std::tie)

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, std

Consider I have a custom type (which I can extend):

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    string b;
};
```

How can I make an instance of this object assignable to a `std::tie`, i.e. `std::tuple` of references?

```
Foo foo = ...;

int a;
string b;

std::tie(a, b) = foo;
```

**Failed attempts:**

Overloading the assignment operator for `tuple<int&,string&> = Foo` is not possible, since assignment operator is one of the binary operators which have to be members of the left hand side object.

So I tried to solve this by implementing a suitable **tuple-conversion operator**. The following versions fail:

- `operator tuple<int,string>() const`
- `operator tuple<const int&,const string&>() const`

They result in an error at the assignment, telling that "`operator =` is not overloaded for `tuple<int&,string&> = Foo`". I guess this is because "conversion to any type X + deducing template parameter X for operator=" don't work together, only one of them at once.

**Imperfect attempt:**

Hence I tried to implement a conversion operator for the **exact type of the tie**:

- `operator tuple<int&,string&>() const`   <kbd>[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67a8a0a0ad778dec)</kbd>
- `operator tuple<int&,string&>()`   <kbd>[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebf805541348be48)</kbd>

The assignment now works since types are now (after conversion) exactly the same, but this won't work for three scenarios which I'd like to support:

1. If the tie has variables of different but convertible types bound (i.e. change `int a;` to `long long a;` on the client side), it fails since the types have to fully match. This contradicts the usual use of assigning a tuple to a tuple of references which allows convertible types.<sup>(1)</sup>
2. The conversion operator needs to return a tie which has to be given lvalue references. This won't work for temporary values or const members.<sup>(2)</sup>
3. If the conversion operator is not const, the assignment also fails for a `const Foo` on the right hand side. To implement a const version of the conversion, we need to hack away const-ness of the members of the const subject. This is ugly and might be abused, resulting in undefined behavior.

I only see an alternative in providing my own `tie` function + class together with my "tie-able" objects, which makes me force to duplicate the functionality of `std::tie` which I don't like (not that I find it difficult to do so, but it feels wrong to have to do it).

I think at the end of the day, the conclusion is that this is one drawback of a library-only tuple implementation. They're not as magic as we'd like them to be.

#### **EDIT:**

As it turns out, there doesn't seem to be a real solution addressing all of the above problems. A very good answer would explain why this isn't solvable. In particular, I'd like someone to shed some light on why the "failed attempts" can't possibly work.

---

<sup>(1):  A horrible hack is to write the conversion as a template and convert to the requested member types in the conversion operator. It's a horrible hack because I don't know where to store these converted members. In [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1563399789ac028d) I use static variables, but this is not thread-reentrant.</sup>

<sup>(2): Same hack as in (1) can be applied.</sup>

Comment: How about implementing `operator = (tuple<int, string>&, const Foo&)`?

Comment: I'm absolutely astounded about this but there doesn't appear to be a pre-existing duplicate for this excellent question.

Comment: @MagnusHoff: `operator=` must be a member (`[C++11: 13.5.3/1]`) and you can't change the definition of `tuple<int, string>`.

Comment: Well, that defeats *that* strategy. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing `std::make_tuple` is out of the question?

Comment: Why don't you instead do `foo = std::tie(a, b)` and overload  the assignment operator? The assignment from the other way around doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That has a whole different meaning. What I want to do is treat `Foo` similar to a `tuple<int,string>` of which I'd like to "pull out" the members using `std::tie`. I.e. I want `Foo` to behave like a tuple in this context.

Comment: I think the basic issue is as follows: `std::tie` produces a tuple of references, i.e. `tuple<int&, string&>`. Whatever you convert `Foo` to, it cannot contain non-const references for a const conversion operator. Hence the type converted to and the `tie` type don't match. Therefore, the default assignment operator is not viable, and the assignment operator template has to be used. But deduction for this template fails, since `Foo` itself is not a `tuple`.

Comment: `std::tie(a,b) = as_tuple(foo)` is possible of course, but probably not what you want.

Comment: @leemes Okay, that wasn't entirely clear the first time I read it.

Comment: @dyp Regarding the "cannot contain non-const references for a const conversion operator": One of the "imperfect attempts" addresses this issue by hacking away const-ness (hoping that the caller only uses it with `tie` to not produce UB). However this only "solves" problem 3. The core issue for 1. + 2. is the fact that conversion + template type deduction don't play together.

Comment: I get the impression `tuple` (and its mechanisms) has not been meant to adapt custom structure types. [boost.fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html) faces the same problem: no compile-time reflection. You can try to write something manually; either an adapter à la boost.fusion, or a mechanism that uses ADL to dispatch assignment between a tied type and a tuple-like type (including custom structures) to some free function.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. As it turns out, this question is very hard. I edited the question by adding a statement what I expect from a good answer, which I eventually might reward with a bounty.

Comment: The "failed attempts" don't work because template argument deduction (which happens before overload resolution) doesn't consider user-defined implicit conversions (which are considered during overload resolution).

Comment: @T.C. Why do the other attempts work then? After template type deduction fails, does it *then* try to convert (but to *what*)? I don't see the whole picture. Is there a (non-templated) overload for the exact types in `operator=`?

Comment: @leemes Shall I post a community-wiki answer that explains why your attempts don't work?

Comment: @leemes There are two non-template `operator=`s that accept the exact same type.

Comment: @dyp Why community-wiki? If you explain the whole picture well, I'd be glad to reward your effort with reputation. Same holds for you, T.C. I didn't know of the overloads, but I guessed there has to be something like that...

Comment: [Here's one idea of a custom `tie` to support user-defined structures](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c1b4e20d1d7ed47)

Comment: What is the usecase? Does it have to be op= ? `std::tie(a,b) << foo;` might not look exactly the same but is probably as convenient to use

Comment: @PlasmaHH It should be as intuitive as possible for usage with a tie on the left hand side. One possible alternative is a different operator, another one is a non-std tie, yet another something with `.to_tuple()` or `to_tuple(...)` before using with `std::tie`. However, I wanted to know if it is really not possible to implement it as `std::tie(...) = ...`.

Comment: I find `friend auto as_tie(Self&&self){` to be a great Koenig operator: I use it in `==`, `<`, Koenig `swap`, etc.  And it makes your code `std::tie(a,b) = as_tie(foo);`, which is pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Why the current attempts fail

`std::tie(a, b)` produces a `std::tuple<int&, string&>`.
This type is not related to `std::tuple<int, string>` etc.

`std::tuple<T...>`s have several assignment-operators:

- A default assignment-operator, that takes a `std::tuple<T...>`
- A tuple-converting assignment-operator *template* with a type parameter pack `U...`, that takes a `std::tuple<U...>`
- A pair-converting assignment-operator *template* with two type parameters `U1, U2`, that takes a `std::pair<U1, U2>`

For those three versions exist copy- and move-variants; add either a `const&` or a `&&` to the types they take.

The assignment-operator templates have to deduce their template arguments from the function argument type (i.e. of the type of the RHS of the assignment-expression).

Without a conversion operator in `Foo`, none of those assignment-operators are viable for `std::tie(a,b) = foo`.
If you add a conversion operator to `Foo`,
then only the default assignment-operator becomes viable:
Template type deduction does not take user-defined conversions into account.
That is, you cannot deduce template arguments for the assignment-operator templates from the type `Foo`.

Since only one user-defined conversion is allowed in an implicit conversion sequence, the type the conversion operator converts to must match the type of the default assignment operator exactly. That is, it must use the exact same tuple element types as the result of `std::tie`.

To support conversions of the element types (e.g. assignment of `Foo::a` to a `long`), the conversion operator of `Foo` has to be a template:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    string b;
    template<typename T, typename U>
    operator std::tuple<T, U>();
};
```

However, the element types of `std::tie` are references.
Since you should not return a reference to a temporary,
the options for conversions inside the operator template are quite limited
(heap, type punning, static, thread local, etc).

Comment: As a side note: I guessed they had the same issue with `std::pair` when they wanted to make it fully (i.e. seamingless) compatible with a two-component `std::tuple`. Hence they needed to add this overload. [with they := standard committee]

Comment: @leemes Yes, that's why there are dedicated overloads of the constructor and assignment-operators *built into `std::tuple`*. Tying those two classes together looks to me like a backwards compatibility hack.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because I read the question as "How to make a type tie-able?" and this doesn't answer the question. It says that we cannot do this while fulfilling certain requirements (or elegantly), but there are alternatives to `std::tie`.

Comment: @dyp I remember I once read in a meta thread that whenever a question has "no answer" (i.e. it is not possible to do what is requested), a viable answer would explain why this is the case (and might suggest an alternative).

Answer (score 7):

There are only two ways you can try to go:

1. Use the templated assignment-operators:
   You need to publicly derive from a type the templated assignment-operator matches exactly.
2. Use the non-templated assignment-operators:
   Offer a non-`explicit` conversion to the type the non-templated copy-operator expects, so it will be used.
3. There is no third option.

In both cases, your type must contain the elements you want to assign, no way around it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

struct X : tuple<int,int> {
};

struct Y {
    int i;
    operator tuple<int&,int&>() {return tuple<int&,int&>{i,i};}
};

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    tie(a, b) = make_tuple(9,9);
    tie(a, b) = X{};
    tie(a, b) = Y{};
    cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
}
```

On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/315d4a43c62eec8d

Comment: Both your solutions fail op demand 1, supporting conversions, demand 2, supporting const members, and `const struct Y` can't be converted failing demand 3..

Comment: @MSalters Deriving from a tuple should allow conversions (with the assignment operator template of `std::tuple`) and const members.

Comment: @dyp On the other hand, deriving from `tuple` is somewhat impractical.

Comment: @MSalters Option 1 only fails 2, while option 2 fails all the nice things too. Anyway, I already said so, and that it won't get better.

Comment: @Loopunroller Agreed; there's no reason IMHO to derive from `tuple` here - you could simply use `tuple` directly. The OP seems to want to adapt an existing structure to the tuple mechanisms.

Comment: Well, if I inherit from `tuple` (aren't we told to not derive from std classes?) I loose named members. Also, my structure is in fact a composition of multiply inherited types with one member each. Like: `struct A { int a; }; struct B { string b; }; struct Foo : A, B {};` This won't work together with the idea of inheriting from tuples.

Comment: @dyp I think someone should write an answer that explains why it doesn't work and explain alternatives.

Comment: @Loopunroller Yeah, I'm in particular interested in an explanation why my failed attempts don't work (see my bold edit in the question).

Comment: @leemes: I outline all the ways your custom type can be assignable to `std::tie(...)`, which also explains why your failed attempts don't work: They fall in neither of the two assignable categories.

Comment: What about overloading a custom operator, like `auto operator|(std::tuple<T&, U&> lhs, Foo foo)`?

Comment: @remyabel If any, then `<<`. But it looks ugly / inconvenient / strange when programmers are used to `tie(...) = ...`. They think "wait, why not `=`?"

Comment: The example would be a lot more convincing if it didn't invoke UB and have unspecified output.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Which one has unspecified output or even plain UB?

Comment: @Deduplicator: What do you mean "which one"? The entire program you give in this answer. Initialise your member variable. Read your compiler warnings; they are there to _help you_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The one warning g++ gave is a false positive, and clang++ gave none. I'm using uniform initializations with an empty list for both `X` and `Y`, which means the default ctor (value-initialize all tuple-members) for `X` and aggregate-initialization (value-initialize all `Y`-members) for `Y`. Where is the error?

Comment: Sorry about my previous edit, I rolled it back; I had the same wrong thought than Lightness Races in Orbit... I guess you're right @Deduplicator

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well, eh, meh, fine :P I'd still have picked a distinctive value, though, in order to make this example convincing. Outputting zeroes doesn't fill me with confidence in any particular demonstration.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers already explain, you have to either inherit from a `tuple` (in order to match the assignment operator template) or convert to the exact same `tuple` of references (in order to match the non-templated assignment operator taking a `tuple` of references of the same types).

If you'd inherit from a tuple, you'd lose the named members, i.e. `foo.a` is no longer possible.

In this answer, I present another option: If you're willing to pay some space overhead (constant per member), you can have both *named members* and *tuple* inheritance simultaneously by inheriting from a *tuple of const references*, i.e. a const tie of the object itself:

```
struct Foo : tuple<const int&, const string&> {
    int a;
    string b;

    Foo(int a, string b) :
        tuple{std::tie(this->a, this->b)},
        a{a}, b{b}
    {}
};
```

This "attached tie" makes it possible to assign a (non-const!) `Foo` to a tie of convertible component types. Since the "attached tie" is a tuple of references, it automatically assigns the *current* values of the members, even though you initialized it in the constructor.

Why is the "attached tie" `const`? Because otherwise, a `const Foo` could be modified via its attached tie.

Example usage with non-exact component types of the tie (note the `long long` vs `int`):

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo(0, "bar");
    foo.a = 42;

    long long a;
    string b;

    tie(a, b) = foo;
    cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
}
```

will print

```
42 bar
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90921a7dbbcf51ee)

So this solves problems 1. + 3. by introducing some space overhead.

Comment: Inheriting from a tuple of references opens a hole in const correctness: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3db6565a6b3f73f4

Comment: @dyp I just wondered what that results in. Just saw the problem in the exact same moment as you wrote that... ;) However, inheriting from tuple of const refs works.

Comment: Yes, but it prevents `foo = tie(a,b)`.

Comment: @dyp True, but that's not exactly part of the question (although it would be nice). I edited the answer to a tuple of const refs, thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of does what you want right? (assumes that your values can be linked to the types of course...)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;


struct Foo {
    int a;
    string b;

    template <template<typename ...Args> class tuple, typename ...Args>
    operator tuple<Args...>() const {
        return forward_as_tuple(get<Args>()...);
    }

    template <template<typename ...Args> class tuple, typename ...Args>
    operator tuple<Args...>() {
        return forward_as_tuple(get<Args>()...);
    }

    private:
    // This is hacky, may be there is a way to avoid it...
    template <typename T>
    T get()
    { static typename remove_reference<T>::type i; return i; }

    template <typename T>
    T get() const
    { static typename remove_reference<T>::type i; return i; }

};

template <>
int&
Foo::get()
{ return a; }

template <>
string&
Foo::get()
{ return b; }

template <>
int&
Foo::get() const
{ return *const_cast<int*>(&a); }

template <>
string&
Foo::get() const
{ return *const_cast<string*>(&b); }

int main() {
    Foo foo { 42, "bar" };
    const Foo foo2 { 43, "gah" };

    int a;
    string b;

    tie(a, b) = foo;
    cout << a << ", " << b << endl;

    tie(a, b) = foo2;
    cout << a << ", " << b << endl;

}
```

Major downside is that each member can only be accessed by their types, now, you could potentially get around this with some other mechanism (for example, define a type per member, and wrap the reference to the type by the member type you want to access..)

Secondly the conversion operator is not explicit, it will convert to any tuple type requested (may be you don't want that..)

Major advantage is that you don't have to explicitly specify the conversion type, it's all deduced...

Comment: Instead of `get<Type>` why not `get<Index>`? This might need another indirection to hook in an index sequence for unpacking the deduced types along with an index.

Comment: @leemes, well, if you have multiple members of the same type, you will need an index (along with a way to get the type), the main downside though is that you don't really know which member should be at which index (without exposing implementation details such as order of members...) I would imagine that in this instance, your best bet would be a "named wrapper" around the reference when the tie is constructed, and extract this as the "type" when forming the tuple..)

Comment: The order is exposed anyway, as the exported tuple is ordered... So I'd resemble the `get`-order exactly like the order the tuple interface is resembled. They can of course be independent of the actual order of the members of the struct.

Comment: @leems, no, you can change the order, for example, in the above code, change `tie(a, b) = foo;` to `tie(b, a) = foo;`, this will work fine as well...

Comment: Ah that's what you meant and that's also your idea of the "type-specified" getters. I don't like it so much because of the unambiguity if members have the same type...

Comment: ... which is the major disadvantage I listed :), if this is a case (i.e members having the same type) your intention to provide a `tie()` access is broken anyway, the only way to fix that would be to provide named wrappers for each member you want to expose via the tie... (e.g. imlpement, `tie(Foo::member_a(a), Foo::member_b(b)) = foo;` and change the `get<>` method to look for the types `member_a` & `member_b`...

Comment: Well, in my opinion the tie access makes sense for an agreed member order (in my case it's a record set from an SQL query, so the client-side programmer chooses the order implicitly over his query). The other use case is something similar to the "swizzling" feature found in OpenGL/CL: `foo.ab` would return a tuple of the members `a` and `b`; `foo.ba` in the other order. This can be implemented similar to your idea in your last comment: `foo.swizzle(Foo::a, Foo::b)` but then why not simply say `tie(foo.a, foo.b)`...

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. I'd love it if someone could point out anything wrong with it.

[Simple Version on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/M66afsod8)

[More Generic Version on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/c5Gndxc98)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>

struct LevelBounds final
{
  int min;
  int max;

  operator std::tuple<int&, int&>() { return {min, max}; }
};

int main() {
    
    int a, b;

    auto lb = LevelBounds{30, 40};
    std::tie(a, b) = lb;

    assert(30 == a);
    assert(40 == b);    
    return 0;
}
```