# C++ Syntax Split ColorA into floats?

Tags: c++

I remember being able to do something like this but I cant remember how. I want to extract the floats from a ColorA data type, what is the shortest syntax to do this in C++?

ColorA(r,g,b,a) = material.getAmbient();

Comment: Depends on what you want to do and how much you can modify. Returning a `std::tuple` or `std::array` from `getAmbient()` sounds good.

Comment: You should be more specific on what you want. Otherwise you won't get any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::tie` here if you're willing to provide a `to_tuple` function. A tuple conversion function [has problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276943/make-custom-type-tie-able-compatible-with-stdtie) with a nastier workaround so this solution is straight forward.

```
struct ColorA
{
    float r, g, b, a;
    auto to_tuple() const
    {
        return std::make_tuple(r, g, b, a);
    }
};

int main()
{
    float r, g, b, a;
    ColorA color;
    std::tie(r, g, b, a) = color.to_tuple();

    return 0;
}
```