# Is there something like `std::tie` for passing values from returned struct into existing variables?

Tags: c++, struct, std-pair, std-tie

I had a code like:

```
std::tie(info.amount, info.price) = GetAmountAndPrice();
```

and the `GetAmountAndPrice` was returning `std::pair` so it worked.

But there was a code review suggesting to change the return type to struct so it's clear what the returned values represent, I think it's quite common point.

But with changing the return type from `std::pair` to some struct, I can't use the `std::tie` to set the members of `info`.
(And I obviously don't want to create a temporary instance of the returned struct to load the values.)

What is a neat modern way to solve this? We use C++17, but I am curious even for C++20, if it improved.

Comment: I think your implementation is fine as it is. However, if you want to create a custom struct an make it tie-able you should have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276943/make-custom-type-tie-able-compatible-with-stdtie

Comment: I believe that this is a direct duplicate.

Comment: Actually there can be a better option, not to make the custom type tie-able, but somehow still pass values into the caller's variables, but I won't be mad if this gets closed.